# Segmentaion fault in c while displaying array

Tags: c, arrays

I have to take 'n' lines of character array(size m), which will have numbers only, and i have to put the numbers in a 2-d integer array.
I am getting segmentation fault while displaying the integer array for second time.

```
int t,m,n,i,j,pix[182][182];
char ch,pixel[183];
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--){

    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);  //take n and m
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("\n");
        scanf("%s",pixel); //take character array
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){ 
            pix[i][j]=pixel[j]-48;  //put numbers in integer array
            dis[i][j]=0;
            printf("%d ",pix[i][j]);  //no error here
        }
    }   
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            printf("%d",pix[i][j]);  //segmentation fault after n-1 lines are displayed
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `scanf("%s",pixel);` will scan `m` numbers of characters?

Comment: What is `dis[i][j]`?

Comment: You have neglected any checking. It's essential with user input. Check the return value from `scanf` and check the range of values that you will use to control array indexing. And please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: scanf, scans any number of characters, here I'm entering m characters, so it will scan m characters @haccks

Comment: dis[i][j] is a global variable @WeatherVane

Comment: scanf is taking correct input as the integer array is correctly displayed for the first time

Comment: Please save us repeating the same stupid questions by posting the MCVE, as in the guidelines. You did not declare a global as `dis[i][j]` did you?

Comment: no it's dis[182][182]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes no effort to check for array boundaries. You need to check that `m` and `n` are less than 182 before proceeding. You should also use a method that protects against a buffer overrun when reading the `pixel` array - e.g `fgets(pixel, sizeof(pixel), stdin)`. Otherwise, depending on the values on `m` and `n` you could have a buffer overrun with unpredictable results.

Your example also did not show the definition of the `dis` array, but you need to do a boundary check there as well.

Aside from that, I am guessing that your input is not laid out quite like your program expects. Performing array boundary checks and asserting as soon as they fail will help you find the discrepancy much quicker.

Comment: Thanks, using fgets instead of scanf solved the problem